# How to use a regular expression to print repeating characters only once and non repeating characters in the same order as they appear in a String?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, regex-group

I'm writing a function to print decimal representation of a rational number( in the form of numerator and denominator) and trying to print the repeating part of digits inside a parenthesis and decimal part remains the same.

```
for EX: 1) 2/3=0.(3)
        2) 2/4=0.5(0)
        3)22/7=3.(142857)
```

For this I tried using a regular expression to capture the repeating characters of decimal part but my regular expression captures the repeating characters once and non repeating characters.

Here is my code...Can someone help me on this!!!

```
div = ((double) num)/deno;
String str = String.valueOf(div);
String arr[] = str.split("\\.");
String wp = arr[0];
String dp = arr[1];
String repeated = dp.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "$1");
System.out.println("repeated is " + repeated);
System.out.println(wp + "." + "(" + repeated + ")");`
```

output I'm getting is:-

```
Input given 22/7
Integer part: 3
Decimal part: 142857142857143
repeating characters captured by regular expression- 142857143
final output-3.(142857143)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are replacing the repeating part, the last `143` is not getting replaced with `` empty string. So it remains in the output.
You can use [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, with regex `(\d+)+\1`, like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        double[] nums = {2.0/3, 2.0/4, 22.0/7};
        for(double d : nums)
            print(d);
    }
    
    static void print(double div) {
        String str = String.valueOf(div);
        String arr[] = str.split("\\.");
        String wp = arr[0];
        String dp = arr[1];
        String repeated = dp;
        Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)+\\1");
        Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(dp);
        if(m.find()) {
            repeated = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(str + " -> "+ wp + "." + "(" + repeated + ")");
        } else {
            System.out.println(str + " -> "+ wp + "." + dp +"(0)");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.6666666666666666 -> 0.(6)
0.5 -> 0.5(0)
3.142857142857143 -> 3.(142857)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is pretty close to work.

Alternative:

```
Matcher matcher =  Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\1").matcher(decimalPart);
String repeated = matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : "0";
```

See alternative in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> divisions = Arrays.asList("2/3", "2/4", "22/7");
    List<String> quotientsAsString = getQuotientsAsString(divisions);
    List<String> repeatedResult = getRepeatedResult(quotientsAsString);
    printResult(divisions, quotientsAsString, repeatedResult);
}

private static void printResult(List<String> divisions, List<String> quotientsAsString,
        List<String> repeatedResult) {
    for (int i = 0; i < divisions.size(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d) %s = %s => %s%n", (i + 1), divisions.get(i)
                , quotientsAsString.get(i), repeatedResult.get(i));
    }
}

private static List<String> getRepeatedResult(List<String> quotientsAsString) {
    //Pre-compile regex before enter loop
    Pattern dotSignPattern = Pattern.compile("\\.");
    Pattern repeatedDecimalPattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\1");
    List<String> repeatedResult = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String quotient : quotientsAsString) {
        String[] quotientParts = dotSignPattern.split(quotient);
        String integerPart = quotientParts[0];
        String decimalPart = quotientParts[1];

        // Pattern in context!!!
        Matcher matcher =  repeatedDecimalPattern.matcher(decimalPart);
        String repeated = matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : "0";

        String resultRepeated = String.format("%s.(%s)", integerPart, repeated);
        String resultZeroRepeated = String.format("%s.%s(%s)", integerPart, decimalPart, repeated);
        String result = repeated.equals("0") ? resultZeroRepeated : resultRepeated;
        repeatedResult.add(result);
    }
    return repeatedResult;
}

private static List<String> getQuotientsAsString(List<String> divisions) {
    //Pre-compile regex before enter loop
    Pattern divSignPattern = Pattern.compile("/");
    List<String> quotientsAsString = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String div : divisions) {
        String[] divParts = divSignPattern.split(div);
        Double dividend = Double.valueOf(divParts[0]);
        Double divisor = Double.valueOf(divParts[1]);
        Double quotient = dividend / divisor;
        quotientsAsString.add(String.valueOf(quotient));
    }
    return quotientsAsString;
}
```

Output:

```
1) 2/3 = 0.6666666666666666 => 0.(6)
2) 2/4 = 0.5 => 0.5(0)
3) 22/7 = 3.142857142857143 => 3.(142857)
```